# PPT change pathfile linked excel file with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a problem regarding a linked Excel File to a Powerpoint presentation.
The Excel file is hosted on an external server which is assigned to a drive letter on all the PC´s in the company. The problem is that the link to the Excel file will randomly changed to where it is located on the external server.

I put a workaround in a Macro :

```
Global fso As New FileSystemObject
Public Sub MaakKoppelingenRelatief()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = 3 Then
            Dim path As String, fname As String
            path = shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
            fname = GetFilenameFromPath(path)
            shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = fname
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
If i > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Changed: " & CStr(i) & " Links", vbOK
Else
    MsgBox "Couldn't find a linked file.", vbOK
End If
End Sub


Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
Dim text1 As String
text1 = "N:\"
If Right$(strPath, 13) <> "\\tsclient\N\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
    GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
End If

If Left$(strPath, 3) <> text1 And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
    GetFilenameFromPath = text1 + strPath
End If
End Function
```

The problem I'm having is in this piece of code :

```
If Left$(strPath, 3) <> text1 And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
    GetFilenameFromPath = text1 + strPath
End If
```

It keeps adding text1 to my path, while it only should do so when text1 is currently not in the first 3 characters of the path.

Can someone help me figure out what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of strpath you are passing? and what should happen if first 3 chars are not the same as text1?

Comment: strPath is the path of the linked Excel File, if the first 3 chars are not the same it should add N:/

Comment: Can you give some example to make it clear as what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text comparison in VBA is kind of irritating sometimes. Instead of using

```
if Left$(strPath, 3) <> text1
```

try this:

```
If StrComp(Left$(StrPath,3),text1) <> 0
```

And if that doesn't work, try this one:

```
If InStr(1,Left$(StrPath,3),text1) = 0
```